# AngularJS radio button group with "other" option that includes a text field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a form with three radio buttons in a group. The third radio button is "Other" and has a text field where the user can enter something in.  I can make the radio button required by adding the "required" property to the radio button's input element.  However, I'd like to make the text field required if and only if the "Other" radio button is selected.  How can I accomplish this?

```html
<p>
    Program:
    <label><input type="radio" ng-model="form.Program" name="Program" value="option 1" required /> option 1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" ng-model="form.Program" name="Program" value="option 2" required /> option 2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" ng-model="form.Program" name="Program" value="other" required /> other</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="form.OtherProgram" ng-disabled="form.Program != 'other'" name="Program_Other" />
</p>
```

The other thing that I'd like to do is to somehow make sure that if "other" is not selected, then $scope.form.OtherProgram is blank, while leaving the text on the screen so that if it's reselected then the user doesn't have to retype what was in the text field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ng-required. Something like

```
<input type ="text" ng-required ="form.Program != 'other'">
```

should work.

Regarding your other issue, you have to employ some controller-logic and some kind of temporary variable for `form.OtherProgram`, using $watch for example.

```
$scope.$watch('form.Program', function(mVal){
  if (angular.isUndefined($scope.form)) return; 

  if(mVal === 'other'){
     $scope.form.OtherProgram = $scope.tmVar;
  } else {
    if($scope.form.OtherProgram !== null){
      $scope.tmVar = $scope.form.OtherProgram;
      $scope.form.OtherProgram = null;
   }
 }
});
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/npvUXpRhB5MYJOstwd88?p=preview

Comment: ng-required worked great; thanks!  any thoughts on how to make my model show an empty string if `form.Program != 'other'` ?  I'm starting to get the sense that i might need to somehow bind to a hidden field (since angularJS is doing 2-way binding).

Comment: You could also try using ng-change to be more expressive. Since angular has as you mention 2-way bindings a hidden input field wouldn't be much help for you.

Comment: your $watch worked, although I noticed a javascript reference error in the console window on page load, so I added the following guard clause to the function:  `if (angular.isUndefined($scope.form)) return;`.  However, if I select "other", type something in, then select option 1, then option 2, then "other" again, the textbox is blank.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up with.  It's a slight variation on hugo's answer.  The main difference being that the "other" text stays visible on the screen.  I just thought I'd document this as an alternative approach.

```html
<p>
    Program:
    <label><input type="radio" ng-model="form.Program" name="Program" value="option 1" required /> option 1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" ng-model="form.Program" name="Program" value="option 2" required /> option 2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" ng-model="form.Program" name="Program" value="Other" required /> Other</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="OtherProgram" ng-disabled="form.Program != 'Other'" ng-change="form.OtherProgram = OtherProgram" ng-required="form.Program == 'Other'" name="Program_Other" />
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="form.OtherProgram" />
</p>
```

And then this $watch function in my controller:

```
$scope.$watch('form.Program', function (mVal) {
    if (angular.isUndefined($scope.form)) return;

    if (mVal === 'Other') {
        $scope.form.OtherProgram = $scope.OtherProgram;
    } else {
        $scope.form.OtherProgram = null;
    }
});
```