# Radio buttons plus a text field in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

Using AngularJS, I would like to create a list of options with radio buttons, the last of which has an empty text field labeled 'Other' for inputing an option that is not in the list. Here's a demonstration of what I have in mind that I [bootstrapped in CodePen](http://codepen.io/azangru/pen/yybyVY). Since Stack Overflow insists on including CodePen code in this message, here it is:

js:

```
angular.module('choices', [])
  .controller("MainCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.color = '';

    $scope.colors = [
      "Red",
      "Green",
      "Blue",
      "Other"
     ];

    $scope.changeColor = function(){
      $scope.color = "Red"
    };

}]);
```

html:

```
<html>
<head>
<body ng-app="choices" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="color in colors">
     <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.color" ng-value="color" id="{{color}}" name="color">
       <label>
         {{color}}
       </label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.color" ng-show="color=='Other'">
  </div>
  <p></p>
  The chosen color is <strong>{{color}}</strong>
  <p></p>
  <button ng-click="changeColor()">Change color</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what I want this demo app to do:

- When I choose any option except for `Other`, the text field should remain blank;
- If I place cursor in the text field, the option `Other` should be selected
- Once I start typing in the text field, the option `Other` should remain selected
- If I change the model that registers the options (in the demo app achieved by clicking the `Change color` button), the corresponding radio button should be selected.

I achieved most of that functionality by using three models (one for color, one for keeping track of radio buttons and one for the `Other` field) and three watchers, but the [resultant app](http://codepen.io/azangru/pen/MYmYmy) seems brittle and fails some of the tests. Could you please suggest a better way for creating such a selector in Angular using as few models and watchers as possible?

*(My question is somewhat similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078146/angularjs-radio-button-group-with-other-option-that-includes-a-text-field) SO question, but I hope is different enough not to be considered a duplicate.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a separate scope property for the other text:

```
$scope.other = '';
```

Add a `colorChanged()` method which will be called when the color is changed. This will set the other text to empty if color is not 'Other':

```
$scope.colorChanged = function () {
    if ($scope.color != 'Other') {
        $scope.other = '';
    }
};
```

This will also need to be called from `changeColor()`. I ended up changing `changeColor` to allow the color to be passed in. It otherwise defaults to red:

```
$scope.changeColor = function(color){
    $scope.color = color || "Red";
    $scope.colorChanged();
};
```

Add `ng-change="colorChanged()"` to radio button:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.color" ng-value="color" id="{{color}}" name="color" ng-change="colorChanged()">
```

Change the textbox to use `other` as the model. Use ng-focus to detect when textbox is focused and then set color to 'Other'. Doing this will select the radio button.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$parent.other" ng-show="color=='Other'" ng-focus="$parent.color = 'Other'"/>
```

Update the display of the color to show the other text:

```
The chosen color is <strong>{{color}}<span ng-if="color === 'Other' && other != ''"> - {{other}}</span></strong>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wg9EDspjuFAMWQcp5fbZ?p=preview)

Comment: So nice, and simple, and clean! :-)

Comment: Thanks. Did my solution end up solving your problem? If so please select my answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I made some very small modifications to your pen [HERE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJRJzR).

The short of it is, instead of having 'Other' as a value, i made it a blank option, with the input actually controlling the value.

```
$scope.colors = [
      "Red",
      "Green",
      "Blue",
      ""
     ];
```

html:

```
  <label >
     {{color || 'Other'}}
   </label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.color" ng-show="color==''">
```

This allows the input to actually control the value of 'Other'...

Comment: The other should really only text in it if the color is other