# Radio button and custom values in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angular-bootstrap

To simulate a question where the the user can choose the options listed below or can enter a custom value

Example :

```
Which color is your Car ? 
( ) RED
( ) BLUE
( ) BLACK
(*) OTHER
    ------------------------------------ 
    | GREEN                            |
    ------------------------------------
```

I use something like this :

https://plnkr.co/edit/j8DlGox9SKxVb1fSkZol?p=preview
Need some ideas on how to make the text-box appear only on seletcting others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Radio buttons plus a text field in Angular.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006673/radio-buttons-plus-a-text-field-in-angular-js) or [AngularJS radio button group with “other” option that includes a text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078146/angularjs-radio-button-group-with-other-option-that-includes-a-text-field)

Comment: Thanks. We can close the question.